# How to join vCards lines

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, replace, vcards

vCard uses a special way to split long lines: At 75 characters, insert a DOS newline *and* a space. Joining therefore means to **replace all occurrences of the sequence "CR, LF, space" with an empty string** and otherwise leave the file alone. The simplest way I've found so far (using [`sed` multi-line search and replace](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/)) is this:

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/\r\n //g;p;}' contacts.vcf
```

That's rather unreadable. Is there an easier way?

Edit: [Resulting implementation](https://github.com/l0b0/vcard/blob/master/join-lines.sh) based on [Peter.O's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40497/3645).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: This `awk` script may be more what you are looking for:

```
awk -vRS='\r\n ' -vORS= 1 contacts.vcf
```

*(original post)*
This `perl` script works, though it is actually longer, even when `sed` is spaced out a bit; and it is quite obviously logically very similar to `sed`. Perhaps `perl` reads the file into memory faster(?), as it doesn't have the *is it, or is it not 1st line?* to deal with...

```
  perl -e 'undef $/; $_=<>; s/\r\n //g; print' contacts.vcf 
#          |         |      |           |
#          ignore    get    substitute  print
#          newlines  all    as needed   result
#          |         |      |           |
# sed -n '1h; 1!H; ${g;     s/\r\n //g; p}' contacts.vcf
```

On the other hand: not to be facetious, but if you can't read a sed script easily and it works, just make it readable.  I can't read any sed script like that!  The one-liner syndrome is simply not suited to sed scripts which go beyond simple substitution... `sed` is more like a text assembly language than a high level scripting language... `perl` is rather cryptic too, but it tends to do big things with its terse syntax.

```
sed -n '
    1h            # if 1st line, copy the pattern space to the hold space
    1!H           # if NOT 1st line, append the pattern to the hold space
    ${            # if this is the last line
      g           # overwrite current pattern with accumulated patterns from hold space
      s/\r\n //g  # make required substitutions
      p           # print the final result. 
    }' contacts.vcf
```